# Two plots on one axis: remove legend items for one of the plots but keep the other

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I have plotted some data on a figure using a combination of approaches (seaborn, matplotlib and pandas).

The plot was set up with `plt.subplots` and has two axes. On one of the two axes I have two plots in an overlay.

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(15, 5))
plot_style = {'marker': 'o', 'color': 'b', 'ms': 10, 'mec': 'b', 'mfc': 'r'}

sns.lineplot(y=year_sum, x=year_sum.index, ax=axes[0])
sns.regplot(y=year_sum, x=year_sum.index, ax=axes[0], ci=0)

month_avg.plot(ax=axes[1],  linestyle='-', label= 'Avg Monthly Storms', **plot_style)
ct.T.plot.bar(legend=None, ax=axes[1], color='black')

axes[0].set_ylabel("Total Recorded Storms")
axes[1].set_ylabel("# of Recorded Storms")
```

And this results:

[image]

However, in the second plot (which is two plots on one axis) I would like a legend item for the blue `lineplot`, but not one showing each and every year from the `dataframe.plot.bar()` call.

However, any time I call `plt.legend()`, it shows both despite the `legend=None` argument.

Is there a way to suppress the legend associated with the Pandas plot and keep the legend associated with the seaborn `lineplot`?

#### Some sample data:

Here's a small subset of the cross-table (`ct`) used to generate the plots.

```
init_date   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
init_date                                               
1851    0   0   0   0   0   1   2   1   1   1   0   0
1852    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   3   1   0   0
1853    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   4   1   0   0
1854    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   2   1   0   0
1855    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   1   0   0   0
```

Comment: could you provide some example data to reproduce the graphs?

Comment: @MiguelTrejo Added. Also I just figured out how to make custom legends from here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/custom_legends.html And that did the trick. I'd be happy for other ways though.